# How to speed up string match against a list of strings?

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings. I am trying to find if any of these strings in the list appear in the english dictionary stored as another list.

I observed the time it takes to find a match grows linearly. However, it becomes way too long when the original list has a few thousand strings.

On my development EC2 instance, it takes ~2 seconds for 100 strings, ~15 seconds for 700 strings, ~100 seconds for 5000 strings, and ~800 seconds for 40000 strings!

Is there a way to speed this up? Thanks in advance.

```
    matching_word = ""
    for w in all_strings:
            if w in english_dict:
                    if matching_word: # More than one possible word
                            matching_word = matching_word + ",  " + w
                    else:
                            matching_word = w
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating a string and extend it you can use list comprehension for that:

```
matching_words = [x for x in all_strings if x in english_dict]
```

Now you can make a string from that list using `", ".join(matching_sords)`.

Another option - using two sets you can use the `&` operator:

```
set(all_strings) & set(english_dict)
```

The result here will be a set with the items you have in both lists.

Comment: Just a note on the last one - set intersection will destroy the order of words found, so if the order is important the first example (list comprehension) should be used - after turning the dictionary into a set, of course.

Comment: Thank you Dekel for the solutions. Unfortunately, list comprehension took the same amount of time. But guess what, the set solution you had given is super fast.

Answer (score 5):

Provided you don't have issues with memory, turn your `english_dict` to `set` (if you do have memory issues, load your dictionary as a `set` to begin with): `english_dict = set(english_dict)`  (prior to the loop, of course)

That should **significantly** speed up the look-up. If that's not enough, you'll have to resort to creating search trees and similar search optimizations.

Comment: Zwer. Thanks for your help. I could solve the performance issue with set solution. Now it is wicked fast!!! Actually, my English dict is very small (just ~15k entries) whereas max(all_strings) is 3,628,800. Now with sets it is taking just less than a second.

Comment: If `all_strings` is that big, and you don't need to preserve the order, then definitely turn both `all_strings` and `english_dict` into sets (or even better - load them as sets) and use `all_strings.intersection(english_dict)` instead.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing. for w in set(all_strings) & set(english_dict) is amazingly fast.